# Bootstrap datetimepicker not working in Stackable Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, datetimepicker

Bootstrap datetimepicker not working in Stackable Bootstrap modal.
I used bootstrap-modal plugin (I found it on https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/) to show stackable modal in one form, on the top modal I tried to add bootstrap datetimepicker but that's not working. Even though the input is in addition to the modal the datetimepicker works.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control bootstrap-datepicker" name="dateAdded" id="dateAdded" data-toggle="datepicker">
```

```js
$(function() { "use strict";
  $('.bootstrap-datepicker').bsdatepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
  });
});
```

I tried:

```
$("#dateAdded").datepicker(); //Not working

$('.bootstrap-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999); //Not Working

$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
  autoHide: true,
  zIndex: 2048,
}); // not working
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be that `$('.bootstrap-datepicker')` will return an **empty array** at the moment you want to initialize the datepicker. This will happen because the `HTML-Element` of your datepicker is not rendered at this moment. (because of the stackable modal)

> You could initialize your datepicker after your datepicker-element is
>   loaded / showen to solve this issue.

*I would create an example, but your provided code is not enough to reproduce.*